# Vue.js (using nginx, Django, + gunicorn) site being served at wrong url: www.myurl.com/static/ instead of www.myurl.com/

Tags: django, vue.js, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am using Vue.js for the frontend and Django RF for the backend of my project.

When developing locally, the project works as intended with the root of the Vue project functioning at localhost:8081/#/ and accessing components like "Example.vue" at localhost:8081/#/example.

I am using nginx on an AWS Ubuntu instance to serve my project. After running 'npm run build', my project is served successfully and works with my Django backend as expected, however, only if accessing the project at [www.myurl.com/static](http://www.myurl.com/static). When navigating to [www.myurl.com](http://www.myurl.com), I am served a basic html page that says "My Project is coming soon". I must have created this file at some point but cannot figure out where it lives in ubuntu file system.

Ultimately I need to fix whatever I've misconfigured so that navigating to [www.myurl.com](http://www.myurl.com) serves my Vue.js files.

This is how my static path is configured with Django's settings.py - I am not sure if this would affect my setup for the Vue files, however, I wanted to include it for reference:

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static- 
files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/myurl.com/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

# Media Files

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
user ubuntu;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml applic>

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is my sites-available project file which inherits from nginx.conf:

```
# File: /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
# This file inherits from the http directive of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Disable emitting nginx version in the "Server" response header field
server_tokens             off;

# Use site-specific access and error logs
access_log                  /var/log/nginx/myproject.access.log;
error_log                   /var/log/nginx/myproject.error.log;

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
  server_name               .myurl.com;
  listen                    80;
  return                    307 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  # Pass on requests to Gunicorn listening at http://localhost:8000
  location / {ESNT WORK EITHER   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect          off;
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/dist;
  }

  # Serve static files directly
  location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/dist;
  }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myurl.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myurl.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the post to include my code and configuration files as blocks instead of images.